# How to increase RX queue size on a netdev type erspan

Tags: linux, networking

Raising it as a new thread as I'm ineligible to comment on an existing similar one yet:
[How to change receive queue length of a network interface in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/284081/how-to-change-receive-queue-length-of-a-network-interface-in-linux)

How do I increase RX queue size on a netdev type erspan in an attempt to prevent RX overrun errors on it? I understand this netdev type is similar in kind to gretap (besides GRE encapsulation it also handles ERSPAN encapsulation):

```
[root@sniffer2 centos]# ip link add dev erspan1 mtu 9100 type erspan seq key 1 erspan_ver 1 
[root@sniffer2 centos]# ip link set erspan1 up
[root@sniffer2 centos]# ifconfig erspan1
erspan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9100
        inet6 fe80::14f6:cbff:fecb:46db  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 16:f6:cb:cb:46:db  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2235281  bytes 311850140 (297.4 MiB)
        RX errors 4042724  dropped 2323  overruns 4042724  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 5  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
[root@sniffer2 centos]# cat /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog
1000
[root@sniffer2 centos]# cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default
212992
[root@sniffer2 centos]# ethtool -g erspan1
Ring parameters for erspan1:
Cannot get device ring settings: Operation not supported
```

Many thanks in anticipation...

Comment: Quote the commands and the outputs to save the formatting. Show output of `ip -d -s -s link show dev erspan1`. Also, `ifconfig` tool is deprecated and you shouldn't use it anymore on new kernels - compatible isn't guaranted. I've looked in the source code and don't find any explicite incrementing `rx_over_errors` of tunnel interfaces.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip -d -s -s link show dev erspan1` command, not `ifconfig`. Don't mix up RX queues, netdev_max_backlog and rmem_* sysctl variables.

Comment: Anton Danilov: I had it formatted at my side since inception and did my best to bring it back into that shape after seeing it all mixed up but never managed to. Please find the output requested here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Buk8-P0SFf0r1sgkUWo-mhwBQNeeN11K  Unfortunately Linux internals are outside my specialization, else I wouldn't be asking it anywhere. Using ifconfig is just an old habit as it keeps returning everything I'm usually after even now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERSPAN interface isn't a hardware interface and it doesn't have real RX queue. Obviously, you cannot change size of it. And the nature of your errors is in something else.

You're using `ifconfig`, that is deprecated and isn't completely compatible with recent kernels. Check the statistics in the output of `ip -s -s -d link show dev erspan1` command and you'll see, what you have **fifo errors**, not **overruns**.

If you have some knowledge of the c programming language, you can look at source code of the [`ip_tunnel_rcv` function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.10/source/net/ipv4/ip_tunnel.c#L374) and find the correspondences between various error types and conditions, under those errors are being incremented.

The fifo errors are caused by [input seqno mismatch](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.10/source/net/ipv4/ip_tunnel.c#L396). I haven't checked it myself, but in [the `man ip-tunnel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-tunnel.8.html) is noted, what seqno isn't working. So, try just disable it with command `ip link set dev erspan1 type erspan noiseq`.

Comment: Spot on Anton: it looks way better at a glance now )  I did see lots of sequencing errors indeed in my mirrored traffic (unless they're totally unrelated) but as I don't know Linux source code I didn't link them to these RX errors and didn't even mention about them in my inquiry. Большое спасибо!! You literally saved us here. I'll still have to do a bit more detailed research into the pcap to ensure no traffic is missing but I'm quite optimistic about it (there are a little bit of RX drops that were there before too - but we should be able to cope with them).

Comment: Btw in reply to "in the man ip-tunnel is noted, what seqno isn't working": the way I understand it is somewhat different - that only the "combo" seq flag doesn't work while iseq/oseq do: "The seq flag is equivalent to the combination iseq oseq. It doesn't work. Don't use it." - so perhaps they just implied using separate flags instead of the combo one when required. At least it looks like iseq (which appears to be on by default) worked perfectly well killing all our out-of-sequence traffic until we turned it off.

Answer (score 1):

Right. When ERSPAN tunnel receives mirrored packet, it will check whether the mirrored packets are in sequence (based on the sequence number in the erspan header). If it's not, then kernel will drop it.

Adding a "noiseq" (no input sequence number) avoids the dropping.
For more details about erspan, see
https://github.com/williamtu/lpc18-erspan/blob/master/paper.pdf

Comment: William Tu:Thank you: looks like this iseq/oseq is on by default and so needs disabling just in case mirrored traffic arrives out of sequence as in our setup with a pair of Cisco N9k switches here (ACI).